# GRUB showing the wrong operating system

Tags: grub2

I have a USB stick with a UNETBOOT produced Lubuntu operating system install.  When I boot from the USB stick, on my computer with Linux Mint (intending to replace it) ONLY the Mint listings are in the GRUB menu.  I tested them and indeed they boot to Mint, which is mind blowing, since the USB stick doesn't have Mint on it!!

On top of that, I tried a different computer and everything worked perfectly.  USB stick showed Lubuntu in the GRUB and it installed.

What could be going on here?  I'm stumped!

Comment: You have a grub menu with a Unetbootin USB?

Comment: Are you sure you have the USB set as the first in the list of bootloader devices in your BIOS settings? It sounds like BIOS is loading the OS from your HDD or SDD instead.

Comment: mchild - yes to both

Comment: Instead of unetboot, you could maybe try the official ubuntu startup disk creator (usb creator) https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/

Comment: the problem seems to be not with the usb stick or the creator - i have tested the usb boot stick on another machine and installed fine.  \

Answer (score -1):

Check your BIOS settings and make sure USB is the first device to boot.
My first answer, hope it helps.

Comment: i thought the same, but that's not it in this case

Comment: also I don't get a GRUB when I boot from the hd

Comment: Could the GNU GRUB on the USB is loading the GNU GRUB from the hard disk?

Comment: How things work? You can try a Lubuntu cd to install. If you dont have grub when boot from hd, what else do you have?

Comment: I have no CD drive on this computer, it's a notebook laptop.

Comment: It's been sitting on my desk for a couple months, I've tried everything and done hours of work on it but am still nowhere.

Comment: I suspect now the problem is with the GRUB somehow dominating my boot, because even the bios sees the usb stick there, it's only after I select it for boot that I get the old grub menu with the current hard disk linux install.